# Regression problem with static and non-static data

Tags: regression, machine-learning, nonlinear-regression

I'm currently working on a project, more specifically, a regression problem. The results are not really that good, and I think it is because the features used, even though are standard features that describe the object, there doesn't seem to be enough difference between data points using those features at point of time I'm making the prediction.

There are more data points available, but these are dynamic data points that change over time. However, including them in modelling will mean that the model can't make a prediction until those data points are available/happened. For example, I might have fixed data about a property features, such as the number of beds, location, etc, but the property might reduce its price in th future.

Is there any way or suggestion where I can make use of both types of data points, and be able to make predictions at any point in time?

Comment: You may need to somehow add a temporal dimension to your features (or maybe adapt a time-series model)

Comment: @gunes do you have any reading material or direction that you recommend that might help? Or a topic/search query that might guide me?